# Is Raphael.js still supported?

Tags: html, svg, raphael

I was about to start using http://raphaeljs.com/ for the first time on quite a big project but I'm wondering about learning a new library that many not be supported.

The github page shows 33 pull requests and the last commit 9 months ago. SHould this should be a concern or should I dive in?

Comment: Who is voting to close this question and why? It seems like a perfectly valid question to ask other programmers.

Comment: I'd say it's not a concern. The author is known for working in sporadic long stretches while ignoring pull requests. Besides, if you need <= IE 8 support then there's no other option. Otherwise you can try Bonsai.js http://bonsaijs.org/

Comment: Thanks Duopixel, I wasn't aware of that. I don't actually need IE8 support so I'm also going to check out Bonsai, the demos look nice.

Comment: Well I'm glad I got an answer before this question was closed. What a ridiculous policy SO has that an interesting and useful question like this which has been favorited, up-voted and answered gets closed because it's "not a good fit for our Q&A format".

Comment: Oh, and one of the people who closed it was the CEO of the company that owns Raphael. Perhaps Michael could have answered my question instead of voting to close?

Comment: @jonhobbs Looks like the answer has been deleted... that, or, I can't see it for some reason. Can you post the gist of what was said? As of Winter 2012/2013 is Raphael a dead project, or is it just awaiting a burst of activity from Dmitry?